# How to resize window in opencv2 python

Tags: python, opencv

I am using opencv 2 with a webcam. I can get the video stream and process it, but I can't seem to figure out a way to resize the display window. I have some video images stacked horizontally, but the image dimension is very small that it's difficult to see things.

My code is pretty simple, and along the lines of this:

```
cv2.namedWindow("main")

....

result = np.hstack((res2, foreground))
result = np.hstack((ff, result))

cv2.imshow("main", result)
cv2.waitKey(20)
```

The [opencv documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html) states:

```
namedWindow
flags – Flags of the window. Currently the only supported flag is CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE . If this is set, the window size is automatically adjusted to fit the displayed image (see imshow() ), and you cannot change the window size manually.
```

But qt backends apparently have extra flags. I don't have a qt backend. Is there a way for me to increase the size of the images so that I can see them?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately you can't manually resize a `nameWindow` window without Qt backend. Your options:

- use `cv2.resize` function to resize the image to desired size prior to displaying the image
- install OpenCV with Qt backend support and use `cv2.namedWindow("main", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL)`

Comment: how did you use resize?

Comment: cv2.resize(image, (0, 0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5) will resize both axes by half while cv2.resize(image, (100,  50)) will resize to have width 100 and height 50 pixels.

Comment: How to add an image to the window?

Comment: How can we check whether we have Qt backend?

Answer (score 18):

Simply write

```
cv2.namedWindow("main", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
```

and then manually resize it to your desired size

```
cv2.resizeWindow('image', 900, 900)
```

Comment: and in the next line: cv2.resizeWindow('image', 900, 900)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `WINDOW_NORMAL` flag when calling the `namedWindow` function as shown below. This will allow you to resize your window.

```
namedWindow("Image", WINDOW_NORMAL);
```

Check the `namedWindow` function documented [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html)

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Windows 11

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to resize the image instead of the window (I never did manage to get window resizing to work):

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('your_image.jpg')
res = cv2.resize(img, dsize=(500,500), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
cv2.namedWindow("Resized", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow("Resized", res)
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to with the resolution of pc camera run this code to confirm

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
width = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
height = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
print(width, height)
```

most likely its 640 x 480 px. You might have to reduce the size of the image to fit the screen

Answer (score -2):

As per the docs, you need to create your window with autosize true.

```
cv2.namedWindow("main", cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
```

Your call to imshow will then automatically resize the window to fit your image.

Comment: The option WINDOW_AUTOSIZE is as default and sets the size of the window to the actual fixed size of the image.