# OpenCV window is resizable, but the image inside the window is not

Tags: python, macos, qt, opencv

I am running this simple OpenCV code written in python in Linux (Ubuntu) and Mac (Mavericks):

```
cv2.namedWindow('normal', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow('normal', img1)
```

In both of them (Mac and Linux) I have installed Qt, so the issue in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815194/how-to-resize-window-in-opencv2-python) is not relevant to my case
I can resize the window in both, but when I am resizing window in Mac the image inside window is not resizing. It is strange to me that I don't have this problem in Ubuntu.

Is this a natural issue in Mac and I should resize the image manually in my code? 
Or there is a missing library or flag that should be set to fix the issue?

Thanks

Comment: no idea why, but this seems to be a rotten apple issue.