# Record video with kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I want to record videos with Kivy but seem to find no resources online on it. I found camera feature which click pictures but no [documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.camera.html#) or functionality
to record video. Some links hinted me on gstreamer.

Comment: Were you able to figure out how to record video with kivy?

Comment: Check out this example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38661129/1689770

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with kivy alone. What you could do though is use another external library such as OpenCv(http://opencv.org/downloads.html) which provides video streaming directly from a camera and display that as an image widget in kivy.

I hope this helps, if you're still having trouble I'll try to get back to you.

Comment: Any examples of opencv in kivy?