# Kivy image does not reload and app stops responding

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, opencv3.0

I am trying to build an application with Python using Kivy. This is what I am trying to achieve:

1. Use input from a video or camera to detect images using a detector that (to simplify) finds all circles in an image, and highlights them somehow, producing a new image as a result. This is done by a class which I call `detector`. Detector makes use of OpenCV for image processing.
2. The detector's output image is written into `display.jpg`
3. A Kivy app has an image field of which `source` is `display.jpg`
4. (*This doesn't work*) I reload the image source using `self.image.reload()` so that my application refreshes the output for the user

Here is my code

```
class GUI(App):

    def build(self):
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(VIDEO_SOURCE)
        self.detector = detector(self.capture)
        layout = GridLayout(cols=2)
        self.InfoStream = Label(text = 'Info', size_hint=(20,80))
        StartButton = Button(text = 'Start', size_hint=(80,20))
        StartButton.bind(on_press=lambda x:self.start_program())     
        self.image = Image(source = 'display.jpg')
        layout.add_widget(self.image)
        layout.add_widget(self.InfoStream)
        layout.add_widget(StartButton)
        layout.add_widget(Label(text = 'Test'), size_hint=(20,20))
        return layout

    def start_program(self):
        while True:
            self.detector.detect_frame()
            self.update_image() # After detecting each frame, I run this

    def update_image(self, *args):
        if self.detector.output_image is not None:
            cv2.imwrite('display.jpg', self.detector.output_image)
            self.image.reload() # I use reload() to refresh the image on screen

    def exit(self):
        self.stop()

    def on_stop(self):
        self.capture.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':            
    GUI().run()
```

What happens is that I can successfully start the application by pressing my `StartButton`. I see output on console proving it's cyclically running through frames from my video stream, and I also see the source image `display.jpg` being updated in real time.

However, after I start, the app window seems to simply freeze. It goes "Not responding" and greys out, never showing any refreshed image.

Following some existing code from other sources, I also attempted to refresh the image using a scheduled task, with `Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_image, dt=1)`, but the result was the same.

Is my way of refreshing the image correct? Are there better ways to do so?

Comment: If you are running a `while True` loop on the main thread, your app will always be unresponsive. You might try the `Clock.schedule_interval` approach again, but use it to replace the entire `while True` loop.

Comment: @JohnAnderson thanks man! That worked! I don't like it forces me to syncrhonise my calls to the detector, but you did find my issue. If you'd like to elaborate an answer I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `while True` loop on the main thread will cause your `App` to be non-responsive. You can eliminate that loop by using `Clock.schedule_interval` as below:

```
class GUI(App):

    def build(self):
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(VIDEO_SOURCE)
        self.detector = detector(self.capture)
        layout = GridLayout(cols=2)
        self.InfoStream = Label(text = 'Info', size_hint=(20,80))
        StartButton = Button(text = 'Start', size_hint=(80,20))
        StartButton.bind(on_press=lambda x:self.start_program())     
        self.image = Image(source = 'display.jpg')
        layout.add_widget(self.image)
        layout.add_widget(self.InfoStream)
        layout.add_widget(StartButton)
        layout.add_widget(Label(text = 'Test'), size_hint=(20,20))
        return layout

    def start_program(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_image, 0.05)

    def update_image(self, *args):
        self.detector.detect_frame()
        if self.detector.output_image is not None:
            cv2.imwrite('display.jpg', self.detector.output_image)
            self.image.reload() # I use reload() to refresh the image on screen

    def exit(self):
        self.stop()

    def on_stop(self):
        self.capture.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':            
    GUI().run()
```

Here is [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38661129/kivy-with-opencv-resizing-image-size) question where the poster is using a `Texture` instead of writing the captured image to a file. Might be a more efficient approach.