# How to resize a small OpenCV videocapture window in Python?

Tags: python, opencv

I am making a rock paper scissors game using tensorflow in which the user can play with the computer through the webcam but the webcam image is too small like this : [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lztBe.jpg)

Here is the snippet where i used OpenCV:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

prev_move = None

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        continue

    # rectangle for user to play
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (100, 100), (500, 500), (255, 255, 255), 2)
    # rectangle for computer to play
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (800, 100), (1200, 500), (255, 255, 255), 2)

    # extract the region of image within the user rectangle
    roi = frame[100:500, 100:500]
    img = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (227, 227))

    # predict the move made
    pred = model.predict(np.array([img]))
    move_code = np.argmax(pred[0])
    user_move_name = mapper(move_code)

    # predict the winner (human vs computer)
    if prev_move != user_move_name:
        if user_move_name != "none":
            computer_move_name = choice(['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'])
            winner = calculate_winner(user_move_name, computer_move_name)
        else:
            computer_move_name = "none"
            winner = "Waiting..."
    prev_move = user_move_name

    # display the information
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    cv2.putText(frame, "Your Move: " + user_move_name,
                (50, 50), font, 1.2, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.putText(frame, "Computer's Move: " + computer_move_name,
                (750, 50), font, 1.2, (255, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.putText(frame, "Winner: " + winner,
                (400, 600), font, 2, (0, 0, 255), 4, cv2.LINE_AA)

    if computer_move_name != "none":
        icon = cv2.imread(
            "{}.png".format(computer_move_name))
        icon = cv2.resize(icon, (400, 400))
        frame[100:500, 800:1200] = icon

    cv2.imshow("Rock Paper Scissors", frame)

    k = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if k == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Is there a problem with my webcam I have tring resizing the frame but it does not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize window in opencv2 python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815194/how-to-resize-window-in-opencv2-python)

Comment: I am new to opencv how do I use `cv2.namedWindow()` in my code

Comment: see https://wiki.qt.io/OpenCV_with_Qt and install the Qt backend, then just put `cv2.namedWindow("<some name>", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resize by using this:

```
width = 1500
height = 1080
dim = (width, height)

frame = cv2.resize(frame, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
```